Can we do Wilson RG in gauge theory in a gauge invariant fashion?
As we all know, cutoff regularization doesn’t work for gauge theory. So won’t the traditional Wilson RG work in gauge theory since it involves explicit cutoff for the same reason.

t'Hooft's Nobel prize is particularly worth giving to him because he proved that dimensional regularisation, which manifestly preserves invariances, works for all orders.

@naturallyInconsistent I only learned that he dealt with renormalizability of gauge theory using dimensional regularization, which is unrelated to the Wilson RG which always involve a cutoff.

As far as I know, your options are doing lattice gauge theory (has a lattice spacing, is gauge invariant, cannot be done analytically), or waving your hands slightly and arguing that from the point of view of the low energy effective theory, dim reg is equivalent to Wilsonian renormalization since the difference between them is due to modes with energies above the cutoff scale, and by construction physics above the cutoff scale is absorbed into the renormalized parameters. (See Section 2.2.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701053).
